# Monthly or One month

Tags: single-word-requests

I am offering membership of my web page and now I have these:

> One Month
>       Semi-Annual
>       Annual
>       Lifetime

I am not sure about *One Month*, maybe I should write *Monthly*? Do these membership names fit together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We offer the following membership choices:

1 month

6 months

12 months

Lifetime

Comment: The ideal answer - all options in the same format (I'd say detached nominal pre-modifiers, as in 6 months(') membership), and as clear as crystal. Mixing detached nominal pre-modifiers and adjectives was never going to sound too hot.

Answer (score 3):

I would choose either:
1 month
6 months
12 months
Lifetime

or 
Monthly (or month-to-month)
Semi-Annual
Annual
Lifetime

with the difference for me being, the first group is a one-time payment/subscription which expires at the end of the time period chosen.  The second (to me) could automatically renew every month/six months/year, or alternatively could suggest a contract set-up, where you may pay every month, but you commit to pay for a year.  [This is not a strict difference between the two groups, just a personal opinion.]